# Get JSON string from onPostExecute to OnCreateView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need get var s (commnet) to onCreatView from onPostExecute (Async Task( in order to draw chart. 
Here my code:
I try many solution but i cant do this.

```
String url;
    HashMap<String, String> params;
    int requestCode;
    PerformNetworkRequest3(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                s = (object.getString("category"));  //need var s -> oncreateview
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);
        if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you be specific, i did not get your issue.

Comment: Hi, Khemraj, variable received value from json, but you want to get the value on OncreateView (fragment), but cant do this
Error: s = null

Answer (score 0):

Just make an callback interface. Final solution would be.

```
new PerformNetworkRequest3("", new HashMap<>(), 0, new PerformNetworkRequest3.OnResult() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String s) {
        // check response here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }
});
```

And replace below with your AsyncTask

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by KHEMRAJ on 7/23/2018.
 */
public class PerformNetworkRequest3 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String url;
    HashMap<String, String> params;
    int requestCode;
    private OnResult onResult;

    private interface OnResult{
        void onSuccess(String s); // you can change this String to any, like JsonObject            
        void onError();
    }

    PerformNetworkRequest3(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode, OnResult onResult) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        this.onResult = onResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            onResult.onSuccess(s);
            if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                s = (object.getString("category"));  //need var s -> oncreateview
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            onResult.onError();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);
        if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**It is just a implementation. You can change callback methods according to your need. Also manage `onError()` and `onSucess()` properly.**

Comment: Cannot do this, I have "public String flag", when i respone json on onSuccess and (same you), then assign to flag -> flag = null. :(

Comment: I did not get you, can you explain a bit more. By the way this is the correct way for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
String url;
HashMap<String, String> params;
int requestCode;

public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}

 PerformNetworkRequest3(Context ctx, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
     context = ctx;
     delegate = asyncResponse;
}

PerformNetworkRequest3(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode) {
    this.url = url;
    this.params = params;
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
        if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            s = (object.getString("category"));  //need var s -> oncreateview

        delegate.processFinish(s);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

    if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
        return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);
    if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
        return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

    return null;
}
```

In your main activity you should implements interface AsyncResponse and overrides its method to get the value.

**MainActivity.java**

```
PerformNetworkRequest3 performNetworkRequest3 = new PerformNetworkRequest3(this, new PerformNetworkRequest3 .AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(Boolean output)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OUTPUT " + output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        performNetworkRequest3.execute("url", "hash_map", "requestCode");
```